# Android Studio Getting Error While onClick

Tags: android, textview

```
 public void Clicking(View view) {

    double one = Double.parseDouble(testtt.getText().toString());
    double two = Double.parseDouble(tessss.getText().toString());
}
```

already;

- testtt [TextView] =  "0.0001974794"
- tessss [TextView] =  "0"

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.Testing_Appi, PID: 2988
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.0001974794"
>           at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1306)
>           at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:547)
>           at com.example.Testing_Appi.MainActivity.testor(MainActivity.java:153)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

I couldn't spot where the error was!

Comment: The exception tells you the cause of the error: one of the `parseDouble` calls have an empty string parameter.

Comment: but already TextView have value "0.0001974794", i just only wanna check if TextView1 bigger than TextView2, but idk where the problem

Comment: Sorry, I misread the exception message. It tells you that the exception is caused by the following: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.0001974794"`. So the problem is with that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example : Find your view by id with view

```java
EditText testttET = view.findViewById(R.id.testtt);
String text = testttET.getText().toString();
```

check if your text is not empty

```java
if(!text.equals("")){
    double value = Double.parseDouble(text);
}
```

Comment: Big thanks you da best, i was miss to check if not null.